# What is the hash (#) resize option in ImageMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

Just came across this resize option '300x300#' and is wondering what the hash option means? There seems to be nothing on this option in the official ImageMagick documentation.

Comment: Could you add a link to where you came across it?

Answer (score 9):

According to [Paperclip's API documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods):

> Paperclip also adds the “#” option (e.g. “50x50#”), which will resize the image to fit maximally inside the dimensions and then crop the rest off (weighted at the center).

So, if you upload a 120x100 image and crop to "50x50#", it'll resize the image to 60x50, and then crop 50x50 using the image's centroid as the anchor (thereby removing 5px from the left and 5px from the right).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at least a couple of gems exist that have independently extended the syntax of ImageMagick's [geometry strings](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) by adding in the `#` option. Paperclip does this, as described in [Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21471883/1709587). [Dragonfly also does this](http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/imagemagick/), giving the `#` the same meaning as in Paperclip. They list a geometry string like `'400x300#'` as meaning:

> resize, crop if necessary to maintain aspect ratio (centre gravity)